# Magento 1.9 Storing JWT in Server to Server communication

Tags: magento-1.9, session

Storing `JWT` in the server side is a bad practice. But most of the time we say that in the context when the `API` calls are made from the client side.

Currently I am doing an implementation where from my backend I need to generate `JWT` token and use in `API` calls in the server side itself. ([Documentation which I am following (Flipkart)](https://ultra-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backend/#access-token-flow))

Here the expiry time of my `JWT` will be 1000 seconds (16.67 minutes).

**Problem:** Where should I store my `JWT` once created so that all the multiple client hits use the same `JWT` until it expires.

**Possible Approaches :**

1. Store in the database, which I think will be a very bad decision considering it has to renew every 16 minutes.
2. Store in the client cookie. But here since its a server to server calls, different client at the same time will have different JWT tokens.
3. I am using Magento 1.9, and we can store values in sessions, customer-sessions etc. It has same problem as 2nd.

Thus, I am looking for possible approaches which can be followed in this case.

Comment: why do you need to store the token? Can't you just generate one per request? this way you don't bother with the expiration

Comment: @Marius Won't it be a very bad practice, generating a new JWT for each api calls to the diff server from each customer, when it already has a expiry time defined.
I am a novice, so asking for clarity on this.

Comment: The expiration date is there in case some tokens "leak". Someone that by any chance gets the token will not be able to use it after a short period of time. I don't think there is a problem in generating tokens per request. (I do it like that). If you want to optimize a bit, in case you need to make multiple calls in the same flow to the third party API, you can use the same token for all calls. But as soon as you start a new flow, you generated a new token.

Comment: @Marius, Okay, I needed this confirmation.
And from flow if I am not wrong then you meant a session right?
Like storing the token in the core/session.

Comment: no. by one flow I mean, one single page request. Or one cli command execution or one single cron execution. Depending on what you are using it for.

Comment: @Marius I will be making call to a 3rd party server. And making a series of API call to that, all calls having JWT  in the header.
So, it won't be a single page request, but independent of those. I am sorry I am not able to understand the context you mentioned for optimisation. In my case what will it be?

Comment: you can skip it for now.